# Дефис, слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, дефис, слитно, раздельно

Как правильно пишется «тайм(-)код(-)история»?

Answer (score 2):

1. Прежде всего надо определиться со словом ***тайм-код***. Дефисное написание считается более частотным. В Викисловаре тоже приводится дефисная запись: тайм-код, Грамота.ру определяет дефис в словах **тайм-менеджмент, тайм-киллер**. Нр в Википедии дается слитное написание (таймкод). В словаре РАН этого слова пока нет.
2. Можно ли объяснить слитную форму для этого слова. В принципе, да. **Timecode** (альтернативно, time code) — это последовательность числовых кодов, генерируемых через регулярные промежутки времени системой синхронизации времени. Timecode используется в производстве видео, управлении шоу и других приложениях, которые требуют временной координации или регистрации записи или действий.

Запись **таймкод** будет обозначать, что это **новое слово** с вполне конкретным значением, а не приложение (определение) для слова код. Примечание. Слово "тайм" в словаре зафиксировано как спортивный термин, но в значении time как время слово может считаться иноязычным элементом.

Так что варианты пока остаются. Надо сказать, что некоторые слова со временем изменили форму написания с дефисной на слитную (онлайн)

3. Если же использовать более частотное слово ***тайм-код***, то надо писать так: ***тайм-код-история,*** то есть это обычная запись несклоняемого иноязычного слова в препозиции.

**Приложение**

Сравнить: ***чат-бот-платформа.*** Автоматизированные программы для переписки можно встретить практически где угодно, особенно на сайтах, связанных с торговлей. Их обобщенное название — «**чат-боты»** — дословно означает «говорящие роботы» и пишется через дефис. Если же речь идет про чат-бот-платформу, то дефисов будет уже два.